# Sentences into words in Python

Tags: python, string, binary-tree, sentence

I'm suppose to store all words in a long sentence in a binary tree stored in a txt.file

Ex english.txt: A blurb or a tag is a statement about a book,
record or video, supplied by the publisher or
distributor, like "The best-selling novel" or
"Greatest hit tunes" or even "Perverse sex".

How do I story every single word of the sentence in the tree?

I have tried:

```
from bintreeFile import Bintree
english = Bintree()
with open("english.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as english_file:
for rad in english_file:
    words = rad.strip().split(" ")
    engelska.put(words)
    engelska.write()
```

This ends up printing ex:

```
['A', 'blurb', 'or', 'a', 'tag', 'is', 'a', 'statement', 'about', 'a', 'book,']
['record', 'or', 'video,', 'supplied', 'by', 'the', 'publisher', 'or']
```

How can i fix this so it only prints the words?

```
A
blurb
or
tag
...etc
```

Comment: It seems like there are two questions here: one about inserting words in a tree, and one about printing elements from a list. It would be ideal if you could stick to one of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

`engelska` is probably a list or an Array of some sort. Arrays/Lists have iterable methods, so you need to do something like

```
for x in engelska:
       print(x)
```